# Network Deploying Adobe Reader DC, is it supported by Adobe Customization Wizard?

Tags: deployment, adobe-reader

I see that Adobe Reader DC was released yesterday. I'd like to get started on a deployment plan, but I can't find any information from Adobe on whether the Adobe Customization Wizard supports it at this point. Additionally, I can't find any information on Adobe's web site regarding the Enterprise Toolkit (the deep, deep documentation on registry settings, etc).

Has anyone found any information yet on deploying Adobe Reader DC?

Thanks,
Beems

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, I no more than posted the question above when I received an email from Adobe. The Adobe Customization Wizard that supports "Adobe Reader DC" will be called version `XII` and is available via the following FTP URL: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/AcrobatDC/misc/.

Additionally, the Enterprise Toolkit documentation is available via the following URL: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Wizard/WizardDC/index.html

---

### Content/keywords for search engines to help others searching this topic:

Welcome to Acrobat Customization Wizard DC (hereafter, the “Wizard”). The Wizard streamlines the task of configuring (customizing) the installer prior to organization-wide deployment. For example, if you have a volume license, you do not need to register and personalize each copy of the product you install. You can customize the installer to not only skip the standard registration questions, but also accept the EULA and fill in your organization name automatically. Other options include:

Leverage existing deployments by copying enterprise files and registry configurations.
Modify the registry (via the Registry Editor) and installer tables (via the Direct Editor) directly.
Optimize the behavior of the installer by setting up silent installation, pre-serialization, reboot options, languages, and so on.
Remove previous versions of Reader and Acrobat.